# Python - set attributes dynamically in for loop

Tags: python, oop

I have the following code:

```
class Test:
    pass

test = Test()

for x in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    test.x = x
    
print(test.__dict__)

{'x': 'c'}
```

This is not what I want. What I want is to set the name of the attribute corresponding to the value of the iteration:

Desired:

```
print(test.__dict__)
   
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setattr`

```
class Test:
    pass

test = Test()

for x in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    setattr(test,x,x)
    
print(test.__dict__)
```